# adding an empty first line inside csv file

Tags: csv, echo

I input data into a csv by 'echo'-ing some values into another csv.

I tried echo "" and in the next line echo "values" but i get intermittent empty lines..

I need empty line only at the start....

Comment: Please show small example code, input data and output data

Comment: give an example of the two csv files, it is unclear how you create **one** csv by echoing into **another** csv

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways of doing this. Since you have not explained your issue with any detail, I am assuming that you are doing something like this:

```
values=$(grep foo csv1.csv)
echo "$values" > csv2.csv
```

At any rate, you seem to be extracting some lines of one csv file and inserting them into another. To add an empty line to the beginning of the new csv file, you do any of these:

```
echo  > csv2.csv; grep foo csv1.csv >> csv2.csv
```

Or, if you have already created `csv2.csv`:

```
awk 'NR==1{print ""} {print}' csv2.csv > tmpfile && mv tmpfile csv2.csv
```

or

```
perl -i -lpe 'print "" if $.==1' csv2.csv
```

or

```
sed -i '1 x;p;x;' csv2.csv
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `sed` as follows to insert a blank line in the beginning of a file `x.txt`:

```
 sed '1 i \
 ' x.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, there are two problems. First, you want an empty line at the start and second, you don't want intermediate blank lines.

**First question**

For this, you can just do `echo "" >> filename` at the beginning of the script.

**Second question**

Info page of echo says

```
`echo' writes each given STRING to standard output, with a space
between each and a newline after the last one.
```

So, the newline that you get is due to the previous echo that you have done. For example `echo "bulbasaur" >> network.txt` inserts "bulbasaur" and also a newline character (`\n`) in the file. So, when you do the second echo like `echo "charmander" >> network.txt`, there will be an empty line between bulbasaur and charmander.

To remove the newline-inserting-behaviour of `echo`, use `echo -n` (See the info or man page of echo). You can do `echo -n "bulbasaur" >> network.txt` followed by `echo -n "charmander" >> network.txt` to remove the inserted newline.